# I want to setup lower repository projects from a higher git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-filter-branch, repository-design

When I started with GIT, I was unfamiliar with the Project Code and just wanted to get all the code under source code control.  The project hierarchy was like this:

```
/Projects/.git  # I put the git repository here, which I think was a big mistake.
/Projects/Project1
/Projects/Project2
/Projects/Project3
/Projects/Project4
/Projects/Project5
```

At one point I ended up creating a sub repository:

```
/Projects/.git (now it contains all of /Projects/Project3/.git changes too)
/Projects/Project1
/Projects/Project2
/Projects/Project3
/Projects/Project3/.git    # I think this will compound the problem of seperation
/Projects/Project4
/Projects/Project5
```

What I really want is to do this:

```
/Projects/(no .git here)
/Projects/Project1/.git
/Projects/Project2/.git
/Projects/Project3/.git
/Projects/Project3/.git
/Projects/Project4/.git
/Projects/Project5/.git
```

I've looked at the filter branch, but don't really understand how I can use it to pull the history out of the higher /Projects/.git repository into separate lower /Projects/Project[1-5]/.git repositories.

I've been looking around and seeing that there is a new git submodule tool.  I'm wondering if this is what I should try to use, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get these projects separated into seperate repositories so that I can get rid of the upper level repository that covers the entire set of projects?

Any help would be appreciated.

Alan

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about history, here's what you can do:

In each of the project folders:

```
git init .

git remote add origin <remote-repo-url e.g. github.com/kae/project1.git>

git add .

git commit -m "Initial Commit"

git push origin master
```

This way all your code will be in its own repo. Delete the outer /Projects/.git just to be safe